# geom_bar changes behavior when variable is factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

Plotting a bar chart for a two-column data frame works just fine:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tibble(.group = c("A","B","A","B","B","A","A","A","A") %>% factor,
       .value = c( 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L)) %>%
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=.value, y=..prop.., fill=.group), position="dodge")
```

[image: Click me. I cannot embed images :(]

However, when the variable is declared as a factor geom_bar produces non-sense results. What is going on in this particular case?

```r
library(tidyverse)
tibble(.group = c("A","B","A","B","B","A","A","A","A") %>% factor,
       .value = c( 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L) %>% factor) %>%
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=.value, y=..prop.., fill=.group), position="dodge")
```

[image: Click me]

Comment: While factors look like characters, they're actually encoded as integers with corresponding text.  Something having to do with that relationship is going on here.  Read this for me: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the x variable is numeric, `geom_bar` calculates the proportion relative to all values of the x variable. When the x variable is categorical (either character or factor class), `geom_bar` calculates the proportion *within* each value of the x variable. You can override this behavior by adding a `group` aesthetic to force `geom_bar` to calculate the proportion relative to all x values. For example:

```
dat = tibble(.group = c("A","B","A","B","B","A","A","A","A") %>% factor,
             .value = c( 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L))

# .value is integer
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=.value, y=..prop.., fill=.group), position="dodge")

# .value is factor
ggplot(dat %>% mutate(.value=factor(.value))) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=.value, y=..prop.., fill=.group), position="dodge")

ggplot(dat %>% mutate(.value=factor(.value))) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=.value, y=..prop.., fill=.group, group=.group), position="dodge")

# .value is character
ggplot(dat %>% mutate(.value=as.character(.value))) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=.value, y=..prop.., fill=.group), position="dodge")

ggplot(dat %>% mutate(.value=as.character(.value))) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=.value, y=..prop.., fill=.group, group=.group), position="dodge")
```

`geom_line` behaves in a similar fashion when the x variable is categorical. For example:

```
set.seed(3)
dat = data.frame(x=rep(paste0(2010:2015, "-", substr(2011:2016,3,4)), 2),
                 y=cumsum(rnorm(12)),
                 group=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=6))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=group, group=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```